# iframe in React giving too many directs issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, embed

I am trying to embed a URL in my React application using an iframe. But on the URL in iframe i am getting "xxxx site redirected you too many times" issue in the browser. Please find below code for reference.

Can anyone please guide me how to resolve this issue.

```
function App() {
  const iframeUrl="https://example.org/";
  const iframeid = "iframe";

  return (
    <div >
      <iframe src= {iframeUrl} id={iframeid}></iframe>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: error]

Comment: This does not seems a React specific issue. Did you tried other websites too?

Comment: @keul I have tried using some local websites they are working...but some sites are not working...could you please let me know if this is specific to some site settings?

Comment: Lot of sites nowadays does not allow to be embedded in iframes. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options
This is a security protection of browsers and you can't do anything to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

It's the binding Error you're not binding `src={iframeUrl} and id={iframeid}` and also check they have proper values too.

Comment: Yes, i am binding proper values. I have tried using some local websites they are working...but some sites are not working...could you please let me know if this is specific to some site settings?